# PowerShell guidelines for -Confirm, -Force, and -WhatIf

Tags: powershell

Are there any official guidelines from Microsoft about when to add `-Confirm`, `-Force`, and `-WhatIf` parameters to custom PowerShell cmdlets? There doesn't seem to be a clear consensus about when/how to use these parameters. For example [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/475).

In the absence of formal guidelines, is there a best practice or rule of thumb to use? Here is some more background, with my current (possibly flawed) understanding:

### -WhatIf

The `-WhatIf` flag displays what the cmdlet *would do* without actually performing any action. This is useful for a dry run of a potentially destabilizing operation, to see what the actual results would be. The parameter is automatically added if the cmdlet's `Cmdlet` attribute has the [`SupportsShouldProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.cmdletcommonmetadataattribute.supportsshouldprocess(v=vs.85).aspx) property set to true.

It seems like (but I'd love to see more official guidance here) that you should add `-WhatIf` if you are ever adding or removing resources. (e.g. deleing files.) Operations that update existing resources probably wouldn't benefit from it. Right?

### -Force

The `-Force` switch is used to declare "I know what I'm doing, and I'm sure I want to do this". For example, when copying a file ([`Copy-File`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849793.aspx)) the `-Force` parameter means:

> Allows the cmdlet to copy items that cannot otherwise be changed, such as copying over a read-only file or alias.

So to me it seems like (again, I'd love some official guidance here) that you should add an optional `-Force` parameter when you have a situation where the cmdlet would otherwise fail, but can be convinced to complete the action.

For example, if you are creating a new resource that will clobber an existing one with the same name. The default behavior of the cmdlet would report an error and fail. But if you add `-Force` it will continue (and overwrite the existing resource). Right?

### -Confirm

The `-Confirm` flag gets automatically added like `-WhatIf` if the cmdlet has `SupportsShouldProcess` set to true. In a cmdlet if you call [`ShouldProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.cmdlet.shouldprocess(v=vs.85).aspx) then the user will be prompted to perform the action. And if the `-Confirm` flag is added, there will be no prompt. (i.e. the confirmation is added via the cmdlet invocation.)

So `-Confirm` should be available whenever a cmdlet has a big impact on the system. Just like `-WhatIf` this should be added whenever a resource is added or removed.

With my potentially incorrect understanding in mind, here are some of the questions I'd like a concrete answer to:

- When should it be necessary to add `-WhatIf`/`-Confirm`?
- When should it be necessary to add `-Force`?
- Does it ever make sense to support both `-Confirm` and `-Force`?

Comment: The -Confirm parameter is also related to the ConfirmImpact cmdlet attribute and the $ConfirmPreference.

Comment: How about [this](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=136658)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't researched whether the documentation is this detailed, but the following are based on my observations:

1. You should use `-WhatIf` for anything that makes a change. Updates are changes that can benefit from `-WhatIf` (e.g., what if you want to make a lot of updates?).
2. `-Force` means "force overwrite of an existing item" or "override a read-only file system attribute". In either case the success of the action depends on the user having permission.
3. `-Confirm` and `-Force` are not mutually exclusive. For example, you can confirm an action to write a file, but the file might be protected with the read-only attribute. In this case the action would fail unless you also specify `-Force`.

Answer (score 5):

As an added observation, `-Force` should not overrule `-WhatIf`. Or in other words: `-WhatIf` has priority over `-Force`.

If you use:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

it will result in the following output:

> What if: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "E:\some directory\".

It will not actually remove the items, even when `-Force` is specified.

This means that you should never write:

```
if($Force -or $Pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to validate that your implementation of these common parameters is compliant to the guidelines (for example, Set-Xxx cmdlets should have -Confirm and -WhatIf), then you can use the excellent `PsScriptAnalyzer` module (which is based on code analysis).

Make sure the module is installed:

```
PS E:\> Install-Module -Name 'PsScriptAnalyzer'
```

Then run PowerShell Code Analysis as follows:

```
PS E:\> Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Path . | FL

RuleName : PSUseShouldProcessForStateChangingFunctions
Severity : Warning 
Line     : 78 
Column   : 10 
Message  : Function 'Update-something' has verb that could change system state. 
           Therefore, the function has to support 'ShouldProcess'.
```

Documentation (and sources) can be found on GitHub: 
https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer

Comment: how to use this?

Comment: @Vijay just like it says above.

Comment: I don't get invoke-scriptanalyzer as a valid command. Do I have to install the module seperately?

Comment: You neee to have the module installed. Use 'Install-Module PsScriptAnalyzer' to do that.

Comment: can you add a link to documentation for script analyzer as i get no output when I run it, I assume that's because it didn't find anything to report about. Running with -verbose shows that yes it didn't find anything

Comment: @Vijay: https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer; or use VSCode (https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the Powershell extension (https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell) which bundles PSScriptAnalyzer.