# How can I confirm that I do want to disable the network adapter in c#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have looked at [How do I automatically answer "yes" to a prompt in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071012/how-do-i-automatically-answer-yes-to-a-prompt-in-powershell) but those solutions did not work.

I have tried adding `-Force` as a parameter but I get the error:

> Get-NetAdapter : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Force'.

I am trying to run the following powershell script in c# to disable WiFi:

```cs
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript($"get-netadapter wi-fi | disable-netadapter");
    PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
}
```

But when I do I get the error:

> A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: Are you sure you want to perform this action?
>   Disable-NetAdapter 'Wi-Fi'"'

How can I tell the script that I do want that to happen, via c#?

Comment: Have you tried Confirm instead of Force? [PowerShell guidelines for -Confirm, -Force, and -WhatIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749333/powershell-guidelines-for-confirm-force-and-whatif) and [PowerShell Common Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Yes, I have tried `-Confirm` too with the same result.

Comment: Sorry I meant `-Confirm:$false` It's an opposite parameter you -don't- want it to confirm

Comment: @HAL9256 either way.

Comment: What about send 'Y' to the Keyboard Buffer?

Comment: @f6a4 I will try and find a way to do that

Comment: @HAL9256 it turns out `confirm:$false` works. still learning the ropes on this powershell stuff!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set the confirmation to false (you *don't* want it to confirm).

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript($"get-netadapter wi-fi | disable-netadapter -Confirm:$false");
    PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
}
```

The other method, when using C#, is to set the confirmation preference to `None` in the Initial Session state:

```
var sessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
sessionState.Variables.Add(new SessionStateVariableEntry("ConfirmPreference", ConfirmImpact.None, ""));

using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create(sessionState))
{
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript($"get-netadapter wi-fi | disable-netadapter");
    PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
}
```